# Prevent other mining softwares to mine my public forked Ethereum chain

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, security, ethminer, blockchain-fork

I forked an Ethereum chain and put it as public, but I only want my **own** software/client to be able to mine. Other miners using ethminer, geth, etc, **cannot mine** and profit from my chain (At least not before they hack and de-compile my software and find a way to mine). Is that possible?

Something I have in my mind:

- An encrypted key needed to be provide for mining, key is decrypted and verified in nodes.
- I create a mining pool and all nodes should only accept answers from my pool (by IP or by an encrypted key).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have a list of miners (identified by address) , and only insert blocks from these miners. The list must be signed by you with your private key and downloaded every certain period by all nodes.

Comment: I think whitelisting by address could not work? Say the miner used our client to mine, so his address is whitelisted, then he can now mine using ethminer with that address.

Comment: @RichardFu, I am not fully understanding your logic, what is the benefit for someone to mine coins using an address that doesn't belong to him? he is never going to get rewards

Comment: the question again is forcing miner to use my own software (geth for CPU-mining) to mine. In your case, miner can start my software and mine with his address. Once the address is whitelisted, he can now happily close my software and start ethminer (GPU-mining) to mine with HIS address.

Comment: I am not getting you, if you allow to mine blocks only to the miners that are listed in the list, he won't be able to mine, ether with CPU or GPU, or whatever.